# Adding vibration manually with incoming call

Tags: android, vibration

Is it possible to vibrate phone with RINGER_MODE_NORMAL? If the audio profile is in 'Ring + No vibration' mode.

If you can, please help in details code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have right now?

Comment: You can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709260/android-detect-if-the-vibrate-setting-in-the-device-is-on-or-off-esp-for-the-c/45240695#45240695

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `switch` and check the current ringer with `getRingerMode` and do what you want next; `setRingerMode`

```
switch( audio.getRingerMode() ){
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
   audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
   audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
   break;
}
```

Also do not forget if you have not already to add permission in your manifest file ...

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**UPDATE**
You can't set both at the same time, one or the other. Also you changed what you wanted according to original question, when you do this it can make thing's more confusing. [**Below**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audiomanager.htm) is more info about `setRingerMode`

[image]

Comment: @Yolin you removed your comment, now I look like I am talking to myself ;)

Comment: haha it happens... I was like what you are commenting after reading your first comment :D

Comment: 'case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
   audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);'

It is fine. But after that the ringer is gone. That is not my point. I need ringer+vibration.

Comment: @436f6465786572 - yeah got that after reading your 2nd comment

Comment: That was a mistake. Sorry. :(

Comment: @YolinNarmi according to your post you wanted "vibrate" if phone is in normal... What you said, "Is it possible to vibrate phone with RINGER_MODE_NORMAL?"

Comment: @YolinNarmi answer provided by 436f6465786572 first checks what mode it is and then sets the phone to VIBRATION mode. If the phone is in ringer mode it will set to VIBRATE on too.. and same for other 2 cases.

Comment: @ShivamChopra thank you for clarifying that a little more for me ;)

Comment: @436f6465786572 - no issues buddy...just trying to help more and more people on SO... it will improve my own skills too...

Answer (score 1):

```
AudioManager mAudioManager;

onCreate() {
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // now for setting it in Vibration mode : 
    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

}
```

tis is the code for setting the phone to VIBRATION mode. Rest you have to check the current state and everything. for full code go [here](http://www.droidacid.com/silent-mode-toggle-app-for-android/)

Comment: nice suggestion, could you put more in your answer as link's tend to **die** at time's and then make's it unavailable...

Comment: @436f6465786572 - Thanks for the suggestion but its my own website link(not promoting my website in anyway), in office so dont get much time to write all the code as developing env is not available right now.