# Android; detect if the Vibrate setting in the device is on or off, esp for the case when it rings but does not vibrate

Tags: android, vibration, android-vibration, android-settings

App requirement: To detect when a phone is on *Ringing mode with the Vibrate Setting being OFF* 
***so the problem comes down to : detect whether the Vibrate Setting is OFF or ON***

Relevant information:

To start with, 
[Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) has no method like `isVibratorModeOn()`  and the 
[Flags related to Vibrate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED_ACTION) and [EXTRA_VIBRATE_...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#EXTRA_VIBRATE_TYPE)  are all marked deprecated with:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 16. Applications should
>   maintain their own vibrate policy based on current ringer mode that
>   can be queried via getRingerMode().

But under [getRingerMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode()), we won't exactly know if the vibrate setting is off or not with [RINGER_MODE_NORMAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

> It will vibrate if the vibrate setting is on.

Now the [getVibrateSetting()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getVibrateSetting(int)) is also deprecated.

Code which works for detecting the `RINGER_MODE` on *most devices and o.s. versions including [Android M on Nexus 6](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html):

```
 if(audioManager.getRingerMode()!=AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT){
            if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
```

*Exception: Nexus 5 - 5.1.1, probably for all Lollipop versions

I feel its very surprising if this has been missed or i've made the big(gest) silly mistake by missing something obvious. Hopefully, this isn't a waste of your time.

Here's more to explain the problem:
`RINGER_MODE_SILENT`scenario covered:
[image: Scenario Covered - ringer silent mode]

`RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE` scenario covered:
[image: Scenario Covered - ringer vibrate mode]

***DETECTING THIS IS THE PROBLEM:***
[image: Problem senario - ringer volume high, vibrate setting off]

Screenshot crops from Android M, Nexus 6

Comment: `(1 == Settings.System.getInt(ApplicationController.getInstance().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING, 0)` -works for Lollipop and M on Nexus...but that constant was added in API level 23, the same condition does not work in 4.4.2 - Micromax device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

the solution is a bit twisted, using a deprecated method in one of the loops, it has worked on all devices i have tested; those of brands; motorola, samsung, htc, lg, xiaomi, micromax, sony

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        
if (audioManager.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
   //ensuring it is not on silent
   if (audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) {
      //  if it is on vibrate mode , esp for api 23
   } else if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
             //  else check whether the volume is not 0
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
             if (audioManager.getVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER) == AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON  
 || audioManager.getVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER) == AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ONLY_SILENT) { //need to add this to detect a specific scenario in xiaomi device
       // if the device o.s version is not 23 this part works
              }
            }
if ((1 == Settings.System.getInt(ApplicationController.getInstance().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING, 0))) { 
       // the constant VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING was added in api 23
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modified solution to the one given:

Even for API < 23 and API 23 this works fine. It seems fine if you do not use deprecated methods for previous APIs. Tested on Samsung, Motorola, OnePlus, Google Pixel, Google Nexus

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int mode = am.getRingerMode();

            switch (mode) {
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                    if ((1 == Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING, 0))) {
                        // code here
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "=== ring + vibrate mode ===", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // code here
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "=== ring + no vibrate mode ===", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;

                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                    // code here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "=== in silent mode ===", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                    // code here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "=== in vibrate mode ===", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: thanks for the update, if you could verify on more devices and kindly confirm it, i'l mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Parath's solution written in Kotlin with some updates:

```
private fun shouldVibrateOnCall(): Boolean {
    val audioManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

    // Ensuring it is not on silent
    if (audioManager.ringerMode != RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
        // If it is on vibrate mode
        if (audioManager.ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) {
            return true
            // Else check whether the volume is not 0
        } else if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
            if ((1 == Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING, 0))) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false 
}
```

Hope it saves you some time.